# C# Task completion callback an exceptions

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I have a WindowsForms application that I would like to be able to leverage async Task. There are a couple of issues that I'm having:

How do you handle ContinueWith so you can run continuation in the form?

What if the Form can be closed before the Task completes?

```
private void buttonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    val t = RunSomethingAsync().ContinueWith( p => { OnRunDone(); });
}

private void OnRunDone()
{
    Invoke( p => { button.Enabled = true; });
}
```

1. Is the above code the right way to do this?
2. What happens in the above code if the Form is closed before the Task completes?
3. What if the RunSomethingAsync throws an uncaught exception?

Comment: Why not use `async/await` here instead of `continuewith`? Google that or try it, you will be surprised at how easy it is to implement/write.

Comment: @Igor is completely right.

Comment: Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Not sure how you use async/await with a UI. It seems to me that async/await good for starting multple tasks, and then waiting for them to finish, but I dont understand how you could use it to update a UI. Can you point to a code example of using async/await with WinForms?

Comment: I read the article, and I just dont get it. It seems like you basically have to know a priori if your async code library is going to be used in a UI.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I just didn't quite understand how await/async works. The solution is:

```
private async void buttonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await RunSomethingAsync();
    OnTaskComplete();
}

private void OnTaskComplete()
{
    label1.Text = "Done";
}

private async Task RunSomethingAsync()
{
     await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Is this right? Await doesn't block, so wouldn't the label get set to 'Done' before the async method finished?

Comment: Doug - Yes, this is correct. Await doesnt block the thread, but it doesnt continue with the code in that block until the await returns.